# Use 'Search' method to filter by text in both the <li> and <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

This function currently filters `<li>` elements by the text inside the `<li>` element. How can I modify it so that it will also filter by the text inside the `<li>` tag (such as data-attributes)>.

I've tried changing `($(this).text().search(...))` to `($(this).search(...))` but that just stopped the function from working entirely.

I posted a fiddle with a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/sMEbN/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list li').addClass('visible');
    $('#search').show();    
    $('#filter').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27 || $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val('');    
            $('#list li').removeClass('visible').show().addClass('visible');
    }         
        else {
            filter('#list li', $(this).val());
    }
    });
});

function filter(selector, query) {
  query = $.trim(query);
  query = query.replace(/ /gi, '|');   
  $(selector).each(function() {
    ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0) ? $(this).hide().removeClass('visible') : $(this).show().addClass('visible');
  });
}
```

Comment: Something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sMEbN/4/) ??

Comment: @adeneo - Yes, and thank you :-) I accepted the answer below because it's not case-sensitive (so it more closely reflects the code I posted), but definite up-vote :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(selector).each(function () {
    var data = $.map($(this).data(), function (el) {
        return el;
    }).join(' ');
    ($(this).text() + ' ' + data).search(new RegExp(query, "i")) < 0 
        ? $(this).hide().removeClass('visible')
        : $(this).show().addClass('visible');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMEbN/5/

`$(this).data()` returns all the data attributes, which then can be joined into string.

Comment: why it comes up with `Item 1` if I enter `g`?

Comment: @Bingo - Because the data-attribute in Item 1 contains 'g' (data-style="Long Sleeves, V-Neck")

Comment: @dfsq - Would you mind explaining '$.map($(this)' as well? I've never used a 'map' function ;-)

Comment: @ChayaCooper `$(this).data()` is an object of data attributes, key-value. And `$.map(obj, callback)` creates new array out of `obj` based on returned values by callback. `obj` can be object or array.